# I deleted icon images from IntelliJ and I don't know how to restore them

Tags: java, image, intellij-idea, icons, restore

I accidentally deleted the icons images from IntelliJ and now it shows weird icons.

When I tried to recover then from the trash bin I thought it would restore the icons back but it didn't restore them.

How can I restore them back?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which icons you are referring to exactly, but if you mean that you want to restore the icons to their default appearance, you can do so in Intellij by going to File | Manage IDE Settings | Restore Default Settings. Fair warning, this assumes you want everything about your project configuration to return to its default state, so don't do this unless you want to revert to the default settings.

Go here for more specific instructions: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-project-and-ide-settings.html#restore-defaults

Answer (score 0):

after you take the icons from trash back , to you change the ClassPAth , show the classPath

Comment: I am new to intellij. how to change the class path